# unable to reconnect to login screen after reboot/logout using vnc

Tags: login, lightdm, remote-desktop, vnc, cinnamon

Since upgrading to 17.10 I can no longer reconnect to the login screen in remote sessions using VNC. The only way I can reconnect to a remote session is if I am already logged in, then VNC is able to re-establish a session.

This is a problem when working from home if I need to reboot my Linux server or logout / switch users.

Doesn't VNC run *before* a user logs in?

I am using RealVNC as my VNC server/viewer and Cinnamon as my desktop environment. This combination worked with no problems until I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10.

I have tried installing (re-installing) lightdm and then dpkg-reconfigure lightdm and selecting lightdm. This does allow me to access the login screen, but now my desktop environment is different from cinnamon.

Is there some combination that will allow me to access the login screen remotely and still have the cinnamon desktop environment?

Comment: Surely I can't be the only one to have experienced this. There must be a solution this out there?

Comment: Well, it's been over week since I posted my issue. Isn't there anyone that can comment or suggest a resolution?

Comment: What if you remove the login screen and make it automatically login. In that case, you will directly be presented with your desktop instead of stucking at login screen. I known we should not do auto login as it can be security issues but would it work. What do you think.?

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this behaviour as well... only fix/workaround we could find was to connect via a shell session and run "service lightdm restart" 
We have a suspicion that this behavior might be related to the power setting on the screen and/or screen lock.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I tried it, but the service fails. Also, I am using Cinnamon, so my desktop would not be the same if I logged in under lightdm.

Comment: I also don't know if it is Ubuntu / Cinnamon that is not presenting the screen properly for ReavlVNC to detect it or if it is ReavlVNC that is not interpreting the login screen.

I have not found anything on the RealVNC site relating to this, but I had no problem until the Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade.